# How to show all my arrays with Firebase and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I've some pushes in Firebase, and I've the data. I've separate the arrays side by side, and I want to show they. But, with my code, I just have the last array on my all arrays.

How to show all the arrays side by side ?

My code :

```js
// useEffect()
        let postJSON

        firebase.database().ref('plugins/posts/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
            const json = snapshot.toJSON()

            for (const i in json) {
                const element = json[i]
                postJSON = [element.name, element.description, element.price, element.linkPlugin]

                console.log(postJSON)
                setPost(postJSON.map((x, i) => <p key={i}>{x}</p>))
}
})

// Render

return (
     {post}
)
```

[image: My result in logs]

[image: My result in render]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.database().ref('plugins/posts/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
      const json = snapshot.toJSON()
      const keys = Object.keys(json);
      const postJSON = keys.map(key => {
        const element = json[key];
        return [element.name, element.description, element.price, element.linkPlugin]
      });
      setPosts(postJSON);
    })
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>{posts.map((x, i) => <p key={i}>{x}</p>)}</div>
  )
}
```

as is you are calling `setPosts` 3 times, once for each array item, each time overriding the previous call to `setPosts`. You need to just call it once with an array of arrays

Comment: Yes, but you removed the loop wich serves to get the data, it's normal ?

Comment: I didn't _really_ remove the loop, I just replaced it with an [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This is a bit off topic at this point, but its often considered poor practice to **ever** write a for loop. See [this article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/functional-programming-in-javascript-how-and-why-94e7a97343b) for more information about the benefits of purely functional programming.

Comment: Also I just realized a few issues with my response, so I made some edits